# Accessor method not call properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

my column name like USERDATA in mysql DB and my user model code 
look like below.

```
.....
....

public function getUserDataAttribute($value){

    if($value != null){
      return  $this->directory.$value;
    }
  }

.......
.......
```

My problem was when i set capital word in db not call accessor method .But I set small letter in DB like userdata. properly call accessor method

How to resolve?

I search many ways but not get any proper solution

Comment: I'm not sure about the actual answer, but that is not how you access properties with variables: `$this->directory.$value` this is wrong; `$this->{'directory'.$value}` this is the way;

if you actually want to concatenate the `$this->directory` and the `$value` than disregard my comment

Comment: the easy way to determine how you may access the data, is to dump the object, and check the `attributes` array on the model; you should see the key to use

Comment: How do you access the property? `$model->USERDATA`?